# Is there an ASP.NET ListView control for Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to build Windows Form application that reads info from a SQL database, and I want to display it in a control like an ASP.NET ListView.

This first time I am writing a Windows Form application, but I'm used to programming in ASP.NET and using the tools such as: listview, gridview, etc. I see that there is a GridView control in Windows forms and the possibility to connect it to the SQL DB.

Is there a tool which is identical to the ASP.NET ListView for Windows Forms or some other control to display my data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The toolbox for Windows forms also contains [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwb14tw.aspx) control. Read [The ListView Control](http://visualcsharptutorials.com/windows-forms/listview-control) and [Working with ListView in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/working-with-listview-in-C-Sharp/) to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx).

It has quite a lot of functionality. Check out the [many questions here in SO about it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=datagridview).

And here's an article with [101 ways to manipulate it](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33748).

Comment: That will be like tables, no? i want somthing like listview - that you not limited with the desgin

Comment: If you Google DataGridView, and then click on Images, you can see a lot of examples of DataGridViews. Many of those have links to tutorials, so if you find one you like, you can quickly find out how to do it.